# Prevent destructor called when an exception has been thrown

Tags: php

Is it possible to prevent the destructor to be executed when an exception is thrown?

Basically, my constructor is currently set to save some information to a file. However, this happends even when I've thrown an error when I would assume php would halt and stop all together.

Example:

```
<?php
class Test {
    function __construct() {
        echo "constructor";
    }

    function __destruct() {
        echo "destructor";
    }

    function Hello() {
        echo "Hello World";
    }
}

$foo = new Test;

$foo->Hello();

throw new Exception("Error Processing Request", 1);

// output: constructorHelloWorlddestructor
// expected output: constructorHelloWorld

?>
```

Comment: most here dont speak hypothetical ... but can read code. Be specific, show your code, what you expect and are not getting, and people will be glad to help out.

Comment: First of all it's **destructor**. It's called by PHP Garbage Collector when there is no more references to this object. Make sure that even after error you still have reference to object. Just make sure you do not leave too much trash.

Comment: I'm fully aware that the destructor is called when no more references to the object exists, however, it's still getting called even when an exception is thrown when I would expect PHP to halt.

Comment: Your output is 'constructorHello WorldPHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: ..'. Destructor was not called

Comment: Instead of logging in destructor, why don't you create your own exception class that has a `log` method? The solution **is not** avoiding the destructor call. If you don't want to call the destructor, don't define it.

Comment: @buildok Uhmm that was code that I only just wrote in my response which I have tested outside of my dev environment. It seems to be working as expected. I'm using a custom exception handler which may be the source of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible.

You could do a bunch of hack like registering a excetion handler and assigning a static variable to flag that you are in a error flow and check that variable in the destructor before executing the code. But since you cannot be sure of when the destructor will be call you are not sure if it's after the exception but before the variable assigment.

But overall you are probably not using the destructor for what it's use for, and to be honest I have been developing for 15 years and I count on my one hand how many time I have use a destructor there is normally others more efficient design pattern... More context will be needed.

Answer (score 1):

The php manual says:

> The destructor will be called even if script execution is stopped using exit(). Calling exit() in a destructor will prevent the remaining shutdown routines from executing.

It therefore appears it is not possible to prevent the destructor from being called.

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#language.oop5.decon.destructor